# Does joining/merging two large DataFrames duplicate data and use more RAM?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas `DataFrame`s containing large amounts of data. Let's say they are:

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a" * 10000] * 1000})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b": ["b" * 10000] * 1000})
>>> df1
                                                     a
0    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
1    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
2    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
3    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
4    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
..                                                 ...
995  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
996  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
997  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
998  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
999  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

Each df uses about 9.6 MB of memory, so overall about 20 MB:

```py
>>> df1.info(memory_usage="deep")
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       1000 non-null   object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 9.6 MB
```

Now if I cartesian product them, I end up with a huge `DataFrame`:

```py
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
>>> len(df3)
1000000
>>> df3.info(memory_usage="deep")
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count    Dtype 
---  ------  --------------    ----- 
 0   a       1000000 non-null  object
 1   b       1000000 non-null  object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 18.7 GB
```

So it seems like we are duplicating each of these strings when we merge, and the memory usage goes up to 18 GB (!!).

However, if I ask Python how much memory it's using, it disagrees.

```py
>>> import resource
>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
200512
```

200512 KB is only about 200 MB.

Incidentally if I check my OS memory usage, it definitely doesn't show Python using anywhere near a gigabyte of RAM.

So is Pandas somehow solving this issue by making the merged `DataFrame` only keep pointers to the original data? Or is it actually duplicating everything?

Comment: It might use a copy-on-write scheme, so it shares memory until you modify something.